# Transfer Data from Union to ladder program in Codesys

Tags: compiler-errors, codesys

i'm a automation programmer student and i m currently working on a Codesys Project.
My goal is to get a bool value from a Word variable to use that value into a ladder program.
I am actually trying to use the union structured text to assign a bit for my word value.
by using the Bit variable i was able to make my ladder program but i get a error from these variable "C0230: Type name 'name of the var' not expected in this place.
How could i avoid this error or how could i get a way to go around it?
I would be very happy to learn anything, thank you very much for all the help and sorry for my roughly bad translated english.

Comment: It would help if you added example code so we can better understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Internal variables has its bits accessible using variable_name.bit_number but some I/O variables does not allow it.
An alternative is, at scan begin, move ([function move](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_operator_move/)) you word value to an internal variable and move back at scan end. So you could use this internal_variable.bit_number in your ladder logic.

Comment: @RomainGrimaldi: In that case, you should be sure to accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. That will signal to the community that your question has been answered to your satisfaction—and also reward André Santos for taking the time to contribute a solution.